# React Native: Can you change iOS version for given emulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, emulation

For my React Native app, one user has two devices, both iPhone 11 Pro, but one running iOS 14 and the other iOS 15. They're reporting a bug that occurs on only the iOS 15 one. I know how to get an iPhone 11 Pro emulator running from XCode, but is there a way to specify the iOS version on that emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using `XCode`.

- Open the simulator dropdown,
- Click on `Add additional simulators`.

[image]

Then, click on the `+` for adding a new simulator. You can choose the iOS Version as well as the device. You can download old iOS versions as well and set them for the newly created simulator.

[image]